# Traversing `vm_area_struct`'s of a process

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, mmap

As an extension of an answer to [Traversing all the physical pages of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868921/traversing-all-the-physical-pages-of-a-process) and data here http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-15-sect-1, I had a small question. In the first answer as suggested to traverse the physical pages of a process,

```
struct vm_area_struct *vma = 0;
unsigned long vpage;
if (task->mm && task->mm->mmap)
    for (vma = task->mm->mmap; vma; vma = vma->vm_next)
        for (vpage = vma->vm_start; vpage < vma->vm_end; vpage += PAGE_SIZE)
            unsigned long phys = virt2phys(task->mm, vpage);
```

and referring to an example given in the second link under the heading "**15.1.6. Virtual Memory Areas**", which is

```
# cat /proc/1/maps     look at init
08048000-0804e000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 64652      /sbin/init   text
0804e000-0804f000 rw-p 00006000 03:01 64652      /sbin/init   data
0804f000-08053000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0           zero-mapped BSS
40000000-40015000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 96278      /lib/ld-2.3.2.so   text
40015000-40016000 rw-p 00014000 03:01 96278      /lib/ld-2.3.2.so   data
```

Now my question is, as I traverse will the values of `vm_start` and `vm_end` for the first area be `08048000` and `0804e000`, or will it be `08048000` and `08053000` (one contiguous chunk of memory). I should probably write a program and try it myself, but I am using this data for another project, and it would be very helpful if someone could help be understand this. I basically want to know that, if

```
08048000-0804e000 r-xp 00000000 03:01 64652      /sbin/init   text
0804e000-0804f000 rw-p 00006000 03:01 64652      /sbin/init   data
0804f000-08053000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0           zero-mapped BSS
```

is one "module" belonging to the process, does it have one or multiple `vm_area_struct` data structures.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has a separate `vm_area_struct` for each map section. If you look at the code in `fs/proc/task_mmu.c`, functions `m_start()` and `m_next`, you'll see that the lines in the `maps` pseudo-file are created by iteratively traversing the process `vma` list. Also, note the comment on the `struct vm_area_struct` declaration:

```
/*
 * This struct defines a memory VMM memory area. There is one of these
 * per VM-area/task.  A VM area is any part of the process virtual memory
 * space that has a special rule for the page-fault handlers (ie a shared
 * library, the executable area etc).
 */
```

Clearly, text, data and BSS sections have different page-fault handling rules: Text can't be written at all. Data is read-on-first-access, then copy-on-write. BSS is zeroed-on-first-access.

Comment: So you are saying that each module(If, for example, i consider a module as an elf executable with multiple sections) will have multiple `vm_area_struct` data structures. ?