# LIST_HEAD(clean_pages) is not working in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux, memory, lru, page-replacement

I want to get a clean page list or inactive/active lists.

But when I used `LIST_HEAD(clean_pages)`, `LIST_HEAD(l_inactive)` or `LIST_HEAD(l_active)`, all the lists are empty..

In addition, `LIST_HEAD(l_hold)` is also empty..

Is there any way to get a clean pages from Linux Kernel? Or 
is there any way to traverse all the pages in the page table?

Answer (score 0):

the LIST_HEAD macro declares and initializes an empty list...
you should look at its defintion in include/linux/list.h

maybe these can help:

1. [Page Table Management](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand006.html)
2. [Traversing all the physical pages of a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868921/traversing-all-the-physical-pages-of-a-process)

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your explanation is really helpful for me. but actually I 'm curious that how can I access all the pages(such as traversing page table or page cache..) However, that example shows just one task. Could you help?